# German umlaute in python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, python-requests

I have a serious problem. I have a java service, which receives POST requests. In python I have written a short test program. A shortened version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
filename = "..."
url = "..."
testFile = {'file': open(filename, 'rb')}
payload = {'name': 'müller'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=testFile)
```

The java process now receives a wrong escaped string because "müller" is received as 'm\xfcller'. If I test it within a python program I see that every string in the python dict is escaped in this way.
So how can I handle the problem that my java POST would receive the non escaped "müller"?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why is this a problem? Why can't the java server decode the data (which is something it should be doing anyway)?

Comment: Do you have any hint how to detect and handle it on server side?

Comment: why not send as int array `print([ord(le) for le in "müller"])  #[109, 252, 108, 108, 101, 114]`